# How to use PATCH with Node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

initially I use a post on the route (POST / territories)

```
app.post('/territories', (req, res, next) => { // Cria um produto
    
    const territories = bancoDeDados.salvarTerritorie({
        data:{
        nome : req.body.name,
        inicio : {x : req.body.inicio, y : req.body.inicio},
        fim : { x : req.body.fim, y : req.body.fim},
        área : req.body.fim * req.body.fim,
        pintado_área :  0,
        }        
    },req.body.fim);

    res.send(territories)
})
```

this route returns me:

```
{
    "data": {
        "nome": "potato",
        "inicio": {
            "x": "0",
            "y": "0"
        },
        "fim": {
            "x": "5",
            "y": "5"
        },
        "área": 25,
        "pintado_área": 0
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

Then I need to use the route (GET / squares /: x /: y) to access a specific index of the matrix (one of the mini squares in the giant square). With this route I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2,
    "painted": false  
  },
  "error": false
}
```

My goal is to change the '' painted '' from false to true, using the PATCH route (/ squares /: x /: y / paint) when entering this route, I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2,
    "painted": true
  },
  "error": false
}
```

however when I return with GET (/ squares /: x /: y) to check if it remains painted, I get false again.

I'm not having
successful in this change, I was able to make the PATCH deliver myself as True, however when calling GET again to check, I get False. Does anyone know how to solve?

** EDIT **

Follow my Patch route:

```
app.patch('/squares/:x/:y/paint', (req, res, next) => {
    const x = req.params.x
    const y = req.params.y

    res.send({
        painted : true
    })
})
```

I get the following value from it:

```
{
    "painted": true
}
```

**EDIT 16/12 01:47**

My post route it creates this Matrix, along with a sequential ID.

```
function salvarTerritorie(territorie,area) { //Define o Id seguinte para o territorie ou utiliza um ID definido caso tenha
    if (!territorie.id) territorie.id = sequence.id
    territories[territorie.id] = territorie
    
    var MATRIZ2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < area; i++) {
        MATRIZ2[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < area; j++) {
            MATRIZ2[i][j] = ''
        }
    }

    for (var L = 0; L < area; L++) {
        for (var C = 0; C < area; C++) {
            
            MATRIZ2[L][C] = {
                data: {
                  x: L,
                  y: C,
                  painted: false  
                },
                error: false
              }
        }
    }
```

I tried to reuse the code you sent me:

```
app.patch('/squares/:x/:y/paint', (req, res, next) => {
    const x = req.params.x
    const y = req.params.y
    const changes = req.body;

    const originalInformation = bancoDeDados.retrieveOriginalInformationInMatrix(x, y);
    // originalInformation will be {"x": 1, "y": 2, "painted": false }

    let modifiedInformation = originalInformation
    if (changes.painted !== undefined) {
        modifiedInformation.painted = true // Updates new information with desired changes
    }
    // Other possible changes like changes.x or changes.y

    res.send(modifiedInformation); // Returns modified information back to user
})
```

I created a function with the name of the function you gave:

```
function retrieveOriginalInformationInMatrix(x,y){
    const stringQuadrado = JSON.stringify(territories.matriz)
    const dadosQuadrado = JSON.parse(stringQuadrado)
    return dadosQuadrado[x][y].data.painted = true
}
```

When using Patch, I am getting exactly a single "true" message.

checking the get again, false remains unchanged.

**EDIT 16/12 02:41**

I got a breakthrough thanks to the help I'm getting, I managed to make him insert a new painted simultaneously, but I couldn't change the value of the existing one.
With the function passed on by IcyBloom:

```
app.patch('/squares/:x/:y/paint', (req, res, next) => {
    const x = req.params.x
    const y = req.params.y
    const changes = req.body;
    const originalInformation = bancoDeDados.retrieveOriginalInformationInMatrix(x, y);
    // originalInformation will be {"x": 1, "y": 2, "painted": false }
    let modifiedInformation = originalInformation
    if (changes.painted !== undefined) {
        modifiedInformation.data.painted = true // Updates new information with desired changes
    }
    // Other possible changes like changes.x or changes.y
    res.send(modifiedInformation); // Returns modified information back to user
})
```

I am getting the following result:

```
{
    "data": {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 4,
        "painted": false
    },
    "error": false,
    "painted": true
}
```

I need to change the existing painted one instead of creating a new one. But I'm not getting it.

Comment: Can you post the server side code? Is PATCH handled on the server?

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated the questioning, I believe the whole situation is much more explained. See if you can understand the whole context.

Comment: Can we see the server side code for how you are handling your PATCH request? For example, the portion of your server code that is `app.patch(.....)`

Comment: I put my Patch route on the question.

I don't know if I'm using it correctly. I looked for some content about and was not successful.

Comment: No worries, so your PATCH request is actually not doing any updates at all, it is simply returning

`{ "painted": true }`

You need to add the logic of updating the specific index of your matrix yourself.  You will have to retrieve the original information at the specific index (which should already be implemented based on your GET request), modify this information and save it, then return the new information through `res.send`

Comment: Do I then need to use a function via the patch route to access my Get, and replace the existing values ​​there, overwriting the data previously entered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So together with my comment, here's a rough example of how your PATCH API should look like

```
app.patch('/squares/:x/:y/paint', (req, res, next) => {
    const x = req.params.x
    const y = req.params.y
    const changes = req.body;

    const originalInformation = retrieveOriginalInformationInMatrix(x, y);
    // originalInformation will be {"x": 1, "y": 2, "painted": false }

    let modifiedInformation = originalInformation
    if (changes.painted !== undefined) {
        modifiedInformation.painted = changes.painted // Updates new information with desired changes
    }
    // Other possible changes like changes.x or changes.y
    saveModifiedInformation(x, y, modifiedInformation);

    res.send(modifiedInformation); // Returns modified information back to user
})
```

You might be wondering what `req.body` is. When sending a PATCH request, its much like your POST request where the changes are in the request body. So in the example above, my envisioned `req.body` will be:

```
{
    "painted": "true"
}
```

Edit:
Try modify your `retrieveOriginalinformationInMatrix` function as such

```
function retrieveOriginalInformationInMatrix(x,y){
    const stringQuadrado = JSON.stringify(territories.matriz)
    const dadosQuadrado = JSON.parse(stringQuadrado)
    return dadosQuadrado[x][y]
}
```

This should return `{"x": 1, "y": 2, "painted": false }`

Next, insert this function into the original example (see above, I have added it in already):

```
function saveModifiedInformation(x, y, modifiedInformation) {
    territories.matriz[x][y] = modifiedInformation
}
```

Comment: I believe I have not been able to use your code correctly, I am quite a beginner with Node and Express, I end up having quite difficulties in things that are possibly beasts.

Do you have any tips that can help me achieve the desired result?

Comment: I updated the result of your code in the publication, at least the way I used it.

Comment: I apologise! I forgot to mention that you have to save the modified information back into your matrix, that is all that is missing from the code sample

Comment: IcyBloom, thank you very much for your help, I don't know how I'm going to do to update the matrix, the only function I have would be to "saveTerritorrie" which generates a matrix and adds a sequential ID.

It is used in the POST route, I have no idea how I can update this matrix.

I tried to do it the following way, I'm trying to solve this project from an early age, I apologize, I can't reason properly anymore.

I will inform the code as I put it as the next question. The attempt was also unsuccessful.

Comment: @RenatoZanotelli I have updated my answer. I hope you can understand that with a PATCH (or PUT) request, you need to implement the logic of updating the originalInformation yourself. Just by doing a `res.send` will not update the information you have stored in memory. 

You should be able to update the matrix in memory by just directly accessing it with `territories.matriz[x][y]`

Comment: I managed to do what you told me, previously I had managed to add 2 painted, 1 was false and the other one was true.

I tried to understand what your code did and it worked, Thank you very much !!